# experimental next.js 13 map is not a function

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am using the experimental next.js (ver.13)
Trying to understand what is wrong with my code .. as i am not getting anything and i am simply following the documentation.

it errors : **photos.map is not a function**

```
async function getPhotos() {
  const res = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos');
  return res.json();
}

export default function Photos() {
  const photos = getPhotos();

  return (
    <div>
      {photos.map((photo) => {
        return <div key={photo.id}>{photo.title}</div>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: `getPhotos` is an `async` function, therefore returns a `Promise`, which has no `map` method. You need to `await` on it to get the real value.

Comment: I have tried async/await on both functions... does not work!

Comment: Post that attempt too.

Comment: async function getPhotos() {
  const res = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos');
  return res.json();
}

export default async function Photos() {
  const photos = await getPhotos();

  return (
    <div>
      {photos.map((photo) => {
        return <div key={photo.id}>{photo.title}</div>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

Comment: Are you totally sure `photos` is an array?

Comment: open the link to the API and see : https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos

Comment: strangely the users and or the posts over the  jsonplaceholder is working! It is just the photos one.

Answer (score 1):

Make the `Photos` component async aswell. It's also a good idea to use conditional chaining `?.` on the `photos` array, so if in any case it is undefined, it doesn't throw an error

```
async function getPhotos() {
  const res = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos');
  return res.json();
}

export default async function Photos() {
  const photos = await getPhotos();

  return (
    <div>
      {photos?.map((photo) => {
        return <div key={photo.id}>{photo.title}</div>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[from here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/41853)

if your node version is above 18

```
module.exports = {
  experimental: {
    enableUndici: true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant map over a object
you have to first convert the object to Array using `Object.keys`